# How to do Taylor expansions generally for multivariate functions?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Ok so I have a function like this: $$f(t + 1, z_t + x_t)$$ where $x_t$ equals $z_{t+1} - z_t$.

I want to Taylor-expand this function so that I can get a first-order approximation. How do I do this? I want to expand around $x_t = 0$.

$z_t$ and $x_t$ are random variables, known at time $t$ and $t+1$ respectively, but just treat them as regular variables.

Comment: So it's more likely that I get an answer if I make my question less clear and to-the-point by cluttering it with my own messy and incorrect attempts? Yeah, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: $$
f(t + 1, z_t) + \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_t}\right|_{x_t = 0} x_t + \frac{1}{2}\left.\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_t^2}\right|_{x_t = 0} x_t^2 + \cdots
$$

Comment: check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables)